# How to group all duplicate object to one list and all unique object to another list from a original list in C#?

Tags: asp.net

I have a text file and to read from and convert each line to and object with Id and someText. I would like to group them so that I have two lists: unique list and duplicate list. the data is very big up to hundred of thousand of lines. Which is the best data structure to use? Please provide some sample code in C#. Thanks a lot!

for example:

original list read from text file:

```
{(1, someText),(2, someText),(3, someText),(3, someText1),(4, someText)}
```

unique list:

```
{(1, someText),(2, someText),(4, someText)}
```

duplicate list:

```
{(3, someText),(3, someText1)}
```

Comment: try store data into List<> and then use linq in order to group the duplicate list and create the unique list

Comment: Have you tried something that you need help with? Stack Overflow does not really do opinion questions like "what is the best data structure to use".

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example with LinQ

```
    Random rnd = new Random();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("enterYourPathHere");
        string line = "";
        int cnt = 0; //This will "generate our ids".
        List<KeyValuePair<int,string>> values = new List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>();

        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            //You convert the line to your object (using keyvaluepair for testing)
            var obj = new KeyValuePair<int, string>(cnt, line);
            values.Add(obj);
            //Increment the id on with 50% chances
            if (rnd.Next(0,1) >0.5) cnt++;

        }

        var unique = values.GroupBy(x=>x.Key).Distinct().Select(x=>x).ToList();
        var duplicates = values.GroupBy(x => x.Key).Where(x => x.Count() > 1).Select(x => x).ToList();
```